# JBehave Set mapping between @BeforeStory/BeforeScenario per individual Story/Scenario

Tags: bdd, jbehave

Looking at the code of jBehave I noticed that all the @BeforeStory/Scenarios annotations run for all the Stories/Scenarios present in the purview of JBehave. There doesn't seem to be any one to one correspondence between Stories/Scenarios and @BeforeStory/Scenario annotations. Please correct me if I am wrong. If this is the expected behavior, how can I get a one-to-one mapping of @BeforeStory/BeforeScenarios to stories and the scenarios?

**For your reference this is what i am doing :**

For each text story there is a corresponding *Story.java which extends a SuperStory.java which in return extends JUnitStories. Moreover there exists a *Steps.java corresponding to each text story as well. *Steps.java are injected from a common spring bean inside the SuperStory.java.apart from this there is single LifeCycleSteps extending PerStoriesWebDriverSteps.

**What I am looking to achieve :**

I want to configure my @BeforeStory/@BeforeScenarios to configure in a way such that  execution of story "x" should execute only the  @BeforeStory/Scenarios of the Step "x"

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since JBehave is BDD, you should design your stories such that you only need to have a @BeforeScenario since each step inside the scenario will be run in sequence, any pre-requisites should be done in the @Given or the @BeforeScenario.  Other testing frameworks that are not BDD need a @Before because every step is meant to be designed such that it can be run without any other dependencies.